# Richacl invalid argument when trying to set atributes

Tags: permissions, privileges, acl, xattr, root-filesystem

I've compiled a kernel to use [richacls](http://www.bestbits.at/richacl/), and compiled the richacl's utility, (but not the `e2fsprogs`). I've mounted a loop file with richacl flags

```
/root/fs_prueba_10mb on /media/ext4_con_richacl type ext4 (rw,loop=/dev/loop0,richacl,user_xattr)
```

There is no problem when I do:

```
# richacl --get file
file:
    owner@:rwp---A--Co--::allow
 everyone@:r------------::allow
```

but if I try change the attributes:

```
# richacl --modify facevedo:rwpCo::allow file 
file: Invalid argument
```

I'm using a 64-bit system, I've linked `/usr/lib64/librichacl.so.1` → `/usr/lib/librichacl.so.1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Finally, I was able to set richacls with a version of `richacl-tools` compiled from the commit [`95baa060f677e54de11b00d08aacd563fd059270`](https://github.com/kvaneesh/richacl-tools/commit/95baa060f677e54de11b00d08aacd563fd059270).

It seems that the definition of the kernel richacl-fullset struct `richace_xattr` did not correspond with the definition in `richacl-tools`.